# How to Edit properties for Linked Rig

Tags: animation, rigging

I purchased a rigged character with custom properties like an IK/FK switch. However, I found it impossible to edit when I linked the rig to another scene where I typically animate. Is there a way I can edit the custom switch with the linked rig? Or should I try another method to import my character, such as simply copying and pasting it from the original scene instead of linking it?[image]

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out. So I need to export the ui.py file and loaded to the linked file, then the UI would show up.